# jquery bbq - detect when user clicks back button

Tags: jquery, browser-history, hashchange, jquery-bbq

I've successfully implemented the jQuery BBQ plugin to build a quick prototype, however I am having one small issue related to my particular setup:

- One of the pages, **"#catalogue"**, includes a grid of items that are generated randomly using a function, **"randomItems()"**, triggered on hashchange (when coming from another page).
- The user then clicks on any of these items in the grid to view the **#detailspage**.
- Upon clicking on the browser Back button, I'd like the user to view the **#catalogue** page (which works fine) BUT prevent the page from generating a new set of random items onload (so keep whatever items were last shown).

Is there a way to know that the user has hit the back button, so in that case I don't trigger the **"randomItems()"** function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the items from `randomItems()` in a cache:

```
// save your records here in the cache
var items = [];

$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    var page = window.location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');

    // check first if items has already records in it and check if page is #catalogue
    // if not then call randomItems()
    if (page === 'catalogue' && items.length === 0) {
        items = randomItems();
    }

    // your code here follows
});
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately doing this would prevent other areas of the prototype to work. Within the **#catalogue** page, the user can click on another menu link, which needs to generate a new set of random items. If I used your solution, once I am in the catalogue I couldn't change its contents. Somehow it needs to be all about using the back button, if that's even possible :)

Comment: @ale edited my answer. I added a condition, the caching will only happen if the page is #catalogue

Comment: unfortunately the problem is still the same, because from the #detailspage you can click on something on the menu and trigger a new instance of the catalogue, only with new, random items..

Comment: After looking at your suggestions, I think the solution is to avoid loading random items onload, and trigger the function only when a user actually clicks on a menu item. That way the browser back button won't trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

use the browser's local storage to save the item. first create a javascript representation of the object. Then store it in the localStorage. Retrieve in on page load. Note that you will have to stringify the complex object to store it because the storage only accepts key value pairs

heres a general pattern

```
var foo;
window.onpageload = function(){
   if(localStorage["foo"] == '' | localStorage["foo"] == undefined){
     foo = getrandomItems(); //possibly an ajax call;
     localStorage["foo"] = JSON.stringify(foo);
   else{
     foo = JSON.parse(localStorage["foo"]);
   }
};
```

see http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html and [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) for details

Answer (score 0):

Believe bbq allows you to set and get url parameters, you can use these to determine if you need to randomise.  When the user clicks link to catalog the url is something like:

```
http://yoururl.com/#catalog
```

So this is the "root" url for catalog and whenever the url is this you randomise Items, after randomising the items you add a param to the url so it becomes say:

```
http://yoururl.com/#catalog?r=1
```

This way when the user goes off and looks at an item and then clicks back historic url will contain the `r=1` and as such you do not process the randomise function.

```
function randomiseItems()
{
  // we do not want to randomise
  if(urlParamIsSet("r")) return; 

  // set url param so gets stored in history (replacing current url)
  urlSetParam("r",1); 

  //-- do your code here
}
```

Instead of `urlParamIsSet/urlSetParam` use whatever function bbq provides for you to manipulate url.